# how to erase the shape not context in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I need to erase any of the shapes(like circle, rect) but not whole context, using another brush tool.

```
var brush = new Path.Circle({
    center: event.point,
    radius: 35,
    fillColor: 'red',
});
var eraser = new Path.Circle({
    center: event.point,
    radius: 35
});
```

I tried "destination-out", "clearRect", but nothing work. I need the result exactly similar the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a second canvas, where you'll draw your background, and then, thanks to the `destination-atop` composite mode, keep only the wanted circle of this image, that you'll draw back to your main canvas.

```js
var eraser = function(evt){
  var x = evt.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
  var y = evt.clientY - this.offsetTop;

  oCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  oCtx.drawImage(img, 0,0);

  oCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
  oCtx.beginPath();
  oCtx.arc(x, y, 25, 0, Math.PI*2);
  oCtx.fill();

  ctx.drawImage(offCan, 0,0);
  }

main.addEventListener('mousemove', eraser);


var ctx = main.getContext('2d');

var offCan = main.cloneNode(true);
var oCtx = offCan.getContext('2d');

var draw = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';

  for(var i=0; i<12; i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(Math.random()*300, Math.random()*150, (Math.random()*25)+10, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
    }

  };

var img = new Image();
img.onload = draw;
img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/300/150";


// you should not include it in the doc, it's just for explaining how it works.
document.body.appendChild(offCan)
```

```html
<canvas id="main"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this. :)